# RSelenium doesn't work inside a functionn?

Tags: rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to write a code that scrapes data from https://charts.spotify.com/charts/view/regional-us-daily/latest.

I'm trying to find a way to collect the charts from different dates within a year. I've been using the latest page as a test, and it worked fine. Here's the code:

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)

rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
                             chromever = NULL,
                             verbose = F,
                             port = free_port())

remDr <- rs_driver_object$client
remDr$open()
latest<- "https://charts.spotify.com/charts/view/regional-us-daily/latest"
remDr$navigate(latest)
remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div/header/div/div[2]/a[3]/div[1]')$clickElement()

remDr$findElement("id", "login-username")$sendKeysToElement(list("my_username"))
remDr$findElement("id", "login-password")$sendKeysToElement(list("my_password"))
remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="login-button"]/span[1]/span')$clickElement()
remDr$navigate(latest)

chart <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table')
spotify_html <- chart$getPageSource()
page <- spotify_html %>% unlist()
page <- read_html(page)

SpotifyScrape <- function(x) {
  rank <- numeric()
  track <- character()
  artist <- character()
  streams <- numeric()

  for (i in 1:10) {
    rank_value <- page %>% 
html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[2]/div/span', sep='')) %>% 
html_text()

    track_value <- page %>%
      html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[3]/div/div[2]/a', sep='')) %>% 
html_text()

    artist_value <- page %>%
      html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[3]/div/div[2]/div/span', sep='')) %>% 
html_text()

    streams_value <- page %>%
      html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[7]', sep='')) %>%
html_text()

    rank <- c(rank, rank_value)
    track <- c(track, track_value)
    artist <- c(artist, artist_value)
    streams <- c(streams, streams_value)
  }
  chart <- data.frame(Rank = rank, Track = track, Artist = artist, Streams = streams, Date = dates)
}
table <- SpotifyScrape(latest)
head(table)

url <- "https://charts.spotify.com/charts/view/regional-us-daily/"
timevalues <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day")
finalurl <- paste0(url, timevalues)
head(finalurl)

aggregated_table <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:10) {
  chart <- SpotifyScrape(finalurl[i])
  aggregated_table <- rbind(aggregated_table, chart)
  aggregated_table <- cbind(aggregated_table, timevalues)
}
head(aggregated_table)
```

However, when I put the lines

```
remDr$navigate(x)
chart <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table')
spotify_html <- chart$getPageSource()
page <- spotify_html %>% unlist()
page <- read_html(page)
```

inside the scrape function like this:

```
SpotifyScrape <- function(x) {
  remDr$navigate(x)
  chart <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table')
  spotify_html <- chart$getPageSource()
  page <- spotify_html %>% unlist()
  page <- read_html(page)
  rank <- numeric()
  track <- character()
  artist <- character()
  streams <- numeric()

  for (i in 1:10) {
    rank_value <- page %>%
      html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[2]/div/span', sep='')) %>% 
html_text()

    track_value <- page %>%
      html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[3]/div/div[2]/a', sep='')) %>% 
html_text()

    artist_value <- page %>%
      html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[3]/div/div[2]/div/span', sep='')) %>% 
html_text()

    streams_value <- page %>%
      html_element(xpath = paste('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[', i, ']/td[7]', sep='')) %>%
html_text()

    rank <- c(rank, rank_value)
    track <- c(track, track_value)
    artist <- c(artist, artist_value)
    streams <- c(streams, streams_value)
  }
  chart <- data.frame(Rank = rank, Track = track, Artist = artist, Streams = streams)
}
```

it won't work and give me the error:
`Selenium message:Unable to locate element: //*[@id="__next"]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/table`

Any reason why the code works when I put the html reading outside the function, but not when I put it inside the function?